# Changing form control from user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm trying to changing a user control informations (labels, pictures etc.) from auto added user control. But i cant do it.

Here's my code;

```
        private void KitapButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BıtıkForm BForm = new BıtıkForm();

            BForm.kitapGoruntuleme.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: What is an *auto added user control*? Are you trying to set properties of Controls in a Form from a different class (another Form or anything else)? Try to be more specific in relation to the objects you're dealing with.

Comment: This is most likley a **Scope** issue.  If an instance of `BıtıkForm` was previously created and displayed/added, then you need to keep that reference at Form/Class level so you can access it and manipulate that particular instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use C# too much but It's eventually object oriented. The mistake I made is; I was creating a new instance of 'BıtıkForm' everytime event fired. It could be solved by adding new property where event belongs, and property will carry 'BıtıkForm' object. So It can be managed trough all over the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class BıtıkForm : Form
    {
        //create controls public instance
        public Label label;

        public BıtıkForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //initialize the control 
            label = new Label();
        }
    }
```

Now you can access it from other place like;

```
BıtıkForm BForm = new BıtıkForm();

BForm.label.Visible = true;
```

/////// But my Suggestion do not do it like that instead do it like below ///////

```
BıtıkForm BForm = new BıtıkForm(controlVisible);//Pass the bool value as parameter to the constructor of form
BForm.Show();
```

And then in form

```
public partial class BıtıkForm : Form
        {
            public BıtıkForm(bool controlVisible)
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                //Set Control Visibility
                someControl.Visible = controlVisible;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's still won't work. It's like i'm clicking to button but it's skips the line .

Comment: *Now you can access it from other place like* `BıtıkForm BForm = new BıtıkForm(); BForm.label.Visible = true;`. No, you cannot: `BForm` is not the current instance of the Form, it's a new, totally unrelated, new instance. Setting a Control in this Form won't change anything in the existing.